# Calls to SQLite work in C#/MonoDevelop but crash when program run from command line

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono, monodevelop

Developing on MonoDevelop 3.0.5 and Mono 2.10.9 with SQLite 4.0 on Windows 7.  Using C# and Mono is set for my active runtime. Target framework is Mono/.NET 4.0.

My schema script loads fine into SQLite and I can access it from the sqlite3.exe/sqlite3.dll at the command line with no problems. I can connect to the database and perform select/update/insert and call functions such as count and last_insert_row_id from my C# code when I execute the code from within the MonoDevelop IDE (both run and debug work fine).

When I try to execute the code from the command line and call myprogram.exe, the program crashes at the first database call.  Significant data from the exception appears to be:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Data.Sqlite, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Mono.Data.Sqlite, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'

The database and sqlite3.dll are in the same directory as myprogram.exe. This appears to be a system configuration issue which is not my forte.  Hopefully it is obvious to someone wat I failed to configure on my development machine.

Comment: How *exactly* are you executing the program from the command line?

Comment: C:\<path>\myprogram\bin\Debug\myprogram.exe <param>

Comment: Try `cd`ing to `C:\<path>\myprogram\bin\Debug` before you invoke it. The working directory might be important.

Comment: I tried to invoke the program from within the Debug directory and outside of it.  Results are the same.  I neglected to mention a warning that prints out: WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.  Would turning this on help diagnose the problem?  I have never heard of this feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows 7 x64, please pay attention to bitness.

When running in MonoDevelop (32 bit), your application (compiled as Any CPU) will be launched as 32 bit process. So when you said it runs fine, which means in 32 bit mode it runs fine.

At command prompt (cmd.exe, 64 bit by default), your application will automatically run under 64 bit mode. If it fails in that case, it means you will have to use 64 bit SQLite stuffs (both 64 bit sqlite3.dll and the 64 bit ADO.NET provider assembly). This should be clearly stated somewhere else on SQLite web site or the ADO.NET provider assembly documentation.